# Clave foranea falla en Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

Tengo una tabla que debe guardar las materias de un alumno que se inscribe en un hipotetico curso. Uso la id de los alumnos como clave foranea en la tabla de materias, pero me da el siguiente error:

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: Materias.id_alumno
```

Creo q puede ser un error de diseño, ya q no tengo mucha practica diseñando bases de datos.
Aqui están las sentencias q usé para crear las tablas.

```
cursor.execute(f"""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Estudiantes(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    Nombre VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL, 
    Apellido VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,  
    ci INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Patrimonio INTEGER NOT NULL);
    """)

cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Materias(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    id_alumno VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL, 
    materia1 VARCHAR(250), 
    materia2 VARCHAR(250),
    materia3 VARCHAR(250),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_alumno) REFERENCES Estudiantes(id));
        """)
```

Los arreglos Patrimonio, RtaLiquid y VrCredit estan fuera de la clase, a la que pertenece esta funcion. Esto es basicamente lo que llevan dichos arreglos:

Rta. Liquida
25.000,oo
30.000,oo
40.000,oo
50.000,oo

Patrimonio
100.000,oo
200.000,oo
250.000,oo
300.000,oo

Vr. Crédito
150,oo
200,oo
250,oo
300,oo

Asi proceso los datos para guardarlo:

```
def guardar(datos):
        nombre = datos[0]
        apellido = datos[1]
        ci = datos[2]
        patrimonio = datos[3] 
        rentaLiquida = datos[4]
        materias = datos[5]
        conexion = sqlite3.connect("BD-Estudiantes.db")
        cursor = conexion.cursor()
        #Comparacion de indices para elegir el valor credito
        credito = 0
        a = Patrimonio.index(patrimonio)
        b = RtaLiquid.index(rentaLiquida)
        creditoPatrimonio = Patrimonio[a]
        creditoRtaLiquid = RtaLiquid[b]
        if creditoPatrimonio > creditoRtaLiquid:
            credito = creditoPatrimonio + 260
        else:
            credito = creditoRtaLiquid + 260
     

        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Estudiantes VALUES(NULL, '{nombre}', '{apellido}', {ci}, {patrimonio}, {rentaLiquida}, {credito})")
        
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Materias VALUES(NULL, NULL, '{materias[0]}', '{materias[1]}', '{materias[2]}')")
```

Comment: creo que se debe por que `Materias.id_alumno` es un valor nulo y en la BD has dicho que no debe de ser nulo

Comment: Hice el cambio. Ahora me registra lo que pido, pero pone la clave foranea vacia, aunque la tabla de Estudiantes ciertamente tiene id.

Comment: verifica el valor de `Materias.id_alumno` pues este tiene valor nulo o `None`, seria bueno que pongas como es que obtienes ese valor o de donde viene, ya que este es el problema

Comment: Creo que el problema debe estar en la forma en que adicionas el registro. ¿Podrías compartirel código de cómo adicionas el registro en la tabla?